# Access objects from a popcontroller

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I will explain my problem briefly summarizing as much as I can.

I have a label lets say "Hello" which is found on my RootViewController. I have a popover which appears when I press on a button on my RootViewController.

On that popover, I have another button on it and when I press on it, I want it to change the label on the RootViewController from "Hello" to "Bye Bye".

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Read about `delegates`. Basically you need to define an interface and assign delegate function which PopoverController will call.